# Use VBA loop to lookup values from closed workbook using reference and paste in active workbook using same reference ID

Tags: vba, excel, loops

**I've gone through many iterations of the logic and can't seem to put it together... here is the goal:**

I need to import data from ten workbooks, that are each updated daily with a new sheet titled by the convention "9/28/17"... and copy this information into a master sheet that grows by a column per day.

I think the code should be structured where it loops through the ten defined ranges in the defined sheets looking for a reference value (in an absolute location, first column of master sheet) and returning a value from the closed workbooks that is offset a few columns from the reference id to the right of the reference...**is this possible? If so, how would I write this into the code?**

It seems to me that the userform needs to include the ability to:

- define a location for each of the 10 workbooks (so I can update each month)
- the date (each workbook contains one month of dated sheets)
- add a column on the master sheet to put the retrieved values into, with the date in the first row

**I would greatly appreciate help in determining an appropriate process for the code to follow.** I have pieces of code that would do parts of this using hardcoded references, but due to the possible addition of rows to the database I like the idea of a lookup that would eliminate the need to change the code and provide validation that the data is going in the right places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the structure of the code you would need to write.

```
Sub Project_Plan()

    ' The Master workbook contains this code
    ' Assign this workbook to a Variable
    ' create the column in which to store the day's data
    ' identify that location by variables
    ' write the date in the first row
    ' (the same date defines the names of the worksheets in the 10 workbooks)

    ' Provide the location of the 10 workbooks
    ' Provide their names
    ' For Each of the 10 workbooks
        ' Extract the data from the daily sheet
        ' Write the data to an Array

        ' Find the location in the defined column of
        ' the Master workbook and write the data there
        ' using the array as a source
    ' Next Workbook
End Sub
```

80% of the work described above takes 20% of the total time you will have to devote to the project's completion. 80% of your time will go into preparation of minute detail, such as how to determine the last row of a column where you don't know how many entries there will be.

You seem to have completed about 20% of the preparation for the 20% of the project. You have reached a point of vantage where you can see a myriad of questions coming towards you which you don't even know how to formulate. On this and other forums help is available only after you found the questions.

To further advance your preparations you will need to start. I suggest you take the blueprint I have provided above (which I guess isn't so much different from what you saw yourself) and work your way down. As you come nearer to a solution you will gain a better view of the questions you will need answers for.

My guess is that you will need about 50 lines of code which will throw up about 20 serious questions. Once you found them you will get answers here rather quickly.

Start with a blank code sheet. Write `Option Explicit` at the top, give a meaningful name to your main procedure, and start declaring the variables you will need for the first step. The better the names you give the more time you will save using them.

Comment: I am aware that my question is lacking..I'm fairly new to this level of complexity in VBA, so I wasn't able to verify that the above framework made sense- your answer is exactly what I came here for... will be back with all those specific questions when I have them. Thanks a ton for your help!!

Comment: I'm delighted to see my hopes confirmed and that you consider my effort helpful. Please pay the finders fee: mark the answer as THE answer. Thank you.